# Is it possible to download the images that my friend shared on the facebook automatically? HOW?

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to create an android application which is able to download all images (or even better videos) that my friend shared on the facebook wall.

Is that possible? Should I start with facebook android SDK? From the  I can not find a function to do what I need from [android SDK reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/). Or maybe I need graph APIs to do that?

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: You friend need to login to your app and grant user_photos permission to your app. Then your app can access his/her photos

Comment: Thanks for you answer, if I didn't get it wrong, you are saying. If I would like to download my friend's image. I need to ask him/her to: 1. Install the app. 2. My friend (Not me and can be me) grants the app to access his/her images?  Is there a doc I could find to describe the rule? Cheers :)